# How can I increase the length of the snake and make it follow the head?

Tags: c, algorithm, game-development

Can someone help me to increase the length of the snake and make it follow the head ?

I tried to develop a simple snake game without videos or help and did almost great but cannot figure out how to increase the size of the snake and move it properly.

I'd be very thankful

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

#define LOG(x)            printf("%s\n", x)
#define LOG_ERROR(x)      fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", x)
#define LOG_SDL_ERROR(x)  fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", x, SDL_GetError())
#define global_variable   static
#define internal_function static
#define SCREEN_WIDTH      640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT     480
#define HEAD_SIZE         30
#define APPLE_SIZE        25
#define MAX_LENGHT        10
 
typedef const char* string;
typedef float realNum;
 
typedef struct Snake
{
    SDL_Rect body[MAX_LENGHT];
    int xSpeed;
    int ySpeed;
    int site;
    realNum xPos;
    realNum yPos;
} Snake;
 
typedef struct Apple
{
    int xPos;
    int yPos;
    int size;
} Apple;
void checkColissions(Apple *apple, Snake *snake );

bool initGame(void);
void update(realNum);
void handleEvent(SDL_Event);
void renderGame(void);
void gameOver(void);
void shutdownGame(void);
Snake makeSnake(void);
void renderSnake(Snake *snake);
void updateSnake(Snake *, realNum);
Apple makeApple();
void renderApple(Apple *);
global_variable bool Running;
global_variable SDL_Window *g_pWindow;
global_variable SDL_Renderer *g_pRenderer;
Snake *g_pSnake = NULL;
Apple *g_pApple = NULL;

int
main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    atexit(shutdownGame);

    if (!initGame())
    {
        LOG_ERROR("Failed Initialization");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        Running = true;
        int fps = 330;
        int desiredDelta = 1000/fps;

        SDL_Event event;

        while (Running)
        {
            renderGame();
            update(desiredDelta);
            handleEvent(event);
            SDL_Delay(rand() % 30);
        }
        
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

bool
initGame()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
    {
        LOG_SDL_ERROR("Failed initialization: ");

        return (false);
    }
    else
    {
        g_pWindow   = 
        SDL_CreateWindow("Snake", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        g_pRenderer = 
        SDL_CreateRenderer(g_pWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
        g_pSnake    = (Snake*)malloc(sizeof(Snake));
        g_pApple    = (Apple*)malloc(sizeof(Apple));

        *g_pSnake   = makeSnake();
        *g_pApple   = makeApple();

        if ((g_pApple || g_pSnake || g_pRenderer || g_pWindow) == NULL)
        {
            return (false);
        }

        g_pWindow   == NULL ?  LOG_ERROR("Window failed")   : LOG("Succes Window");
        g_pRenderer == NULL ?  LOG_ERROR("Renderer failed") : LOG("Succes Renderer");
        g_pApple    == NULL ?  LOG_ERROR("Apple failed")    : LOG("Succes Apple");
        g_pSnake    == NULL ?  LOG_ERROR("Snake failed")    : LOG("Succes Snake");

        LOG("Game initialized");

    }

    return true;
}

void
renderGame()
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(g_pRenderer, 0, 80, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(g_pRenderer);
    renderSnake(g_pSnake);
    renderApple(g_pApple);
    SDL_RenderPresent(g_pRenderer);
}

void update(realNum elapsed)
{
    updateSnake(g_pSnake, elapsed);
    checkColissions(g_pApple, g_pSnake);
}

void
handleEvent(SDL_Event event)
{
    SDL_PollEvent(&event);

    switch (event.type)
    {
    case SDL_QUIT:
    {
        Running = false;
    } break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

void
shutdownGame()
{
    if (g_pWindow)
    {
        SDL_DestroyWindow(g_pWindow);
    }

    if (g_pRenderer)
    {
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(g_pRenderer);
    }

    if (g_pApple)
    {
        free(g_pApple);
    }

    if (g_pSnake)
    {
        free(g_pSnake);
    }

    SDL_Quit();

    LOG("Game shutdowned");
}

Snake makeSnake(void)
{
    const int speed = 0;
    Snake snake = {
        .xSpeed = speed,
        .ySpeed = speed,
        .xPos   = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2,
        .yPos   = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2,
        .site   = HEAD_SIZE
    };
    SDL_Rect SnakeRect = {
        .h = snake.site,
        .w = snake.site,
        .x = snake.xPos,
        .y = snake.yPos
    };
    snake.body[0] = SnakeRect;
    return (snake);
}

void renderSnake(Snake *snake)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGHT; i++)
    {
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(g_pRenderer, 0, 0, 100, 255);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(g_pRenderer, &snake->body[i]);
    }
}

void updateSnake(Snake *snake, realNum elapsed)
{
    const Uint8 *keyboardState = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGHT; i++)
    {
        /* code */
    snake->body[i].y += snake->ySpeed * elapsed;
    snake->body[i].x += snake->xSpeed * elapsed;
    }
    
        /* code */
    
    
        /* code */
    
        /* code */
    if (keyboardState[SDL_SCANCODE_W])
    {
        snake->ySpeed = -1;
        snake->xSpeed = 0;
    }
    if (keyboardState[SDL_SCANCODE_D])
    {
        snake->ySpeed = 0;
        snake->xSpeed = 1;
    }
    if (keyboardState[SDL_SCANCODE_A])
    {
        snake->ySpeed = 0;
        snake->xSpeed = -1;
    }
    if (keyboardState[SDL_SCANCODE_S])
    {
        snake->ySpeed = 1;
        snake->xSpeed = 0;
    }

    if (snake->body->x < 0 - HEAD_SIZE)
    {
        snake->body->x = SCREEN_WIDTH + HEAD_SIZE;
    }

    if (snake->body->x > SCREEN_WIDTH + HEAD_SIZE)
    {
        snake->body->x = 0 - HEAD_SIZE;
    }
 
    if (snake->body->y < 0 - HEAD_SIZE)
    {
        snake->body->y = SCREEN_HEIGHT + HEAD_SIZE;
    }

    if (snake->body->y > SCREEN_HEIGHT + HEAD_SIZE)
    {
        snake->body->y = 0 - HEAD_SIZE;
    }
}
 


void
checkColissions(Apple *apple, Snake *snake )
{
    SDL_Rect appleRect = {
        .h = APPLE_SIZE,
        .w = APPLE_SIZE,
        .x = apple->xPos,
        .y = apple->yPos  
    };
        
        if (SDL_HasIntersection(&appleRect, snake->body))
        {
            *g_pApple = makeApple();
        };
     
}
```

Can someone help me to increase the length of the snake and make it follow the head ?

Comment: Since it's C++, not C, skip `malloc` and the `create` functions. Add a constructor that does the necessary initializing instead. Store the instances in `vector`s. You also don't need to `typedef` your `struct`s in C++. They are automatically `typedef`ined.

Comment: As for the problem you ask about, just store the previous head positions in a `vector` of the length you want. Remove the last when the snake moves forward.

Comment: MAX_LENGHT must be a variable so you can grow the snake.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that it is pure C :[

Comment: then why tag it c+? and this has little to do with sdl.

Comment: i've changed it, I'm sorry i am new here.

Comment: If you add the headers you might be in business

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to add the other code.

Comment: If the maximum length of the snake is limited, Using a ring buffer which size is the maximum length may be easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Snake is defined by an array of coordinates, not just one (x,y). You need some kind of circular buffer, that can change capacity. Or you can just use an array, and then change every element of the array with every snake's move. And then you would realize that circular buffer is a really neat idea.

Once you have your buffer, be it an array or circular buffer, the question becomes how to move and enlarge the snake in it. It is simple. To move the snake you add one coordinate to the head, and remove one from the tail of the buffer. When the snake should become bigger you just don't remove the last element in the buffer. Add to the head, but don't remove the tail. This is how circular buffer would be handled. In case of a plain array moving means overwriting everything, and enlarging means adding to the beginning, and moving everything else by one place.